# Should we have an [encoding] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was writing up a question and I found there is no [encoding](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoding). Upon further investigation, there are [486 questions at the time of this writing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=encoding+is%3Aq) with the term "encoding" within them, and I'm sure more than one of them would be applicable to the tag.

Should we create the tag, and if so, who should go through the existing questions to apply it to them?

Comment: I suspect that the 486 questions is an indication that it is a bit too broad. There's questions in there with Huffman encoding, URL encoding, Base 64 encoding... how much does those things have in common really?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Encoding" seems too vague to me to be useful.

Note that we already have specific tags such as:

- [serialization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serialization)
- [escaping](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escaping)
- [url](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url)
- [base64](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base64)
- [unicode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) and [utf-8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8)

Comment: Thanks for that! :) I didn't know if there was a reason, or if it was an oversight. In this case, should it be blacklisted so no one accidentally creates it?

Comment: We generally don't go about preemptively blacklisting things that haven't proven to be a problem.

Comment: Ah, alright. That makes sense. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: soo.. let's go retagging with more specific tags?